# Why is double opt-in necessary? Addressing low deliverability [TEMPLATE]

Tags: email

How can we encourage customers to implement double opt-in? Use the following template to send to the customer:

"Hello Team,

We as a company are diligent about the deliverability of our customers and their and our domain reputation.
While monitoring the area of email marketing on a regular basis, we have detected some irregularities that affect the deliverability of messages.

The current situation negatively affects the deliverability of your emails. Messages may not reach your customers or may be treated as unwanted, which leads to reporting emails as spam. This also results in a less trustworthy reputation for your, and all our customers, shipping address.

A single opt-in policy that you are currently practicing, leads to a reduction in the quality of your contact database and you expose yourself to the presence of contacts in your database that are spamtraps - that is, addresses used to report senders who send marketing content without the required consents.

Sending messages to such addresses results in:
automatic addition of IP addresses and sending domains to spamlists,
sharp drop in reputation for the sending domain and IP addresses,
blocking of message delivery to recipients - due to presence on spam lists and lowered scoring, ESP systems block messages or automatically qualify them as spam
drastically reduce the deliverability of messages and the sales results of email marketing campaigns,

Such actions result in a loss of reputation for us and for you in particular.

We understand that a single opt-in policy is allowed by law, but technically you are incurring a lot of damage that will manifest itself in the long term, and you may already be seeing the first symptoms. Therefore, we highly recommend to use double opt-in policy. Please check also our deliverability materials, which are available on our website. Using them will certainly improve your e-mail marketing. File to download.

Taking care of the above factors will not only improve the deliverability of your emails, but will also affect the future mailings and dispatches of all our customers and the reputation of the domains associated with our system. Improved deliverability can further impact your sales and conversions.

We sincerely encourage you to pay more attention to your messaging.
Our experts are available to assist you at any time if needed.

Best Regards"

Answer (score 1):

Helpful materials:

1. spamtraps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamtrap
2. kamasutra of email marketing: https://www.salesmanago.com/info/definitive-guide-to-email-deliverability.htm
3. best practices in building a database: https://support.salesmanago.com/email-list-building/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).